# Aure B2C Tenant / Active Directory

Tags: sql, azure, directory

Here is my scenario: A new user signs up for our web app using Azure B2C workflow.  The user can sign up with different Identity Providers (Google, Microsoft, Amazon).  The user needs access to a database.  I would like to enroll them as a user with rights in Azure Active Directory that way they can have controlled access to the Azure Sql Database.  I hope this info was helpful.

Comment: There's too much unclear in your question for us to help you. Yes, this is possible. For instance you could use Microsoft Graph to create a user in your own code as soon as a new user signs in. But for users to have access to a database you don't have create an Active Directory user. Could you explain your scenario a bit better? Please refer to [ask].

Comment: I rewrote my original question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding right ,if you are looking for azure ad b2c external user to authenticate to azure sql database in azure ad ,we need to note Azure ad b2c will not allow you to delegate their authentication token to a SQL backend which actually relies on Azure Active Directory.

As you can use Azure Active Directory Authentication for authentication with your Azure SQL Database and  Not Azure AD B2C.Guest users can include users from other Azure Active Directories, or from accounts like @outlook.com, @hotmail.com, @live.com, or @gmail.com. who needs access.

So we need to ensure that the guest user (for example, user@gmail.com) should be  added to your Azure AD and an `Azure AD admin` has been set for the database server which is required for Azure Active Directory authentication.

Then we need to connect to the SQL database as the Azure AD admin or an Azure AD user with sufficient SQL permissions to create users
And run

```
CREATE USER [user@gmail.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

See 1. [Create Azure AD guest users - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-guest-users)  for further details

2. [Azure Active Directory authentication - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview)